# Can expected variance of GLM be expressed through gradients under non-cannonical link functions?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, exponential-family, link-function

In GLMs (generalized linear models), one can typically obtain an estimate of the expected variance of the response variable given the predictors as a transformation of the same parameter that defines the mean.

Per the paper:
Jørgensen, Bent. "Exponential dispersion models." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological) 49.2 (1987): 127-145.

When using a canonical link function, the inverse of the expected variance van be expressed as the derivative of the inverse link function w.r.t. the mean:
$$
V(\mu)^{-1} = \frac{\partial \tau^{-1}(\mu)}{\partial \mu}
$$

So for example, for a logistic regression model, where
$$
P(y = 1|x) = \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x)+1} = \mu = p
$$

the variance is known to be:
$$
V(y|x) = p (1 - p)
$$

the link is the logit function
$$
g(p) = \log \frac{p}{1 - p}
$$

And the expected variance can be calculated through it as
$$
V(y|x) = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial g(p)}{\partial p}}
$$
$$
p = \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x)+1}
$$

without any apriori knowledge that $var(p) = p (1 - p)$

However, if one were to switch to a non-cannonical link function, such as probit, where
$$
g(p) = \Phi^{-1}(p)
$$

the relationship would no longer hold.

Now, my question is, given knowledge about the link function, inverse link function, and probability distribution $P(y|x)$ or $P(y|g(x))$, can the expected variance be expressed in terms of those functions plus their derivatives?

Comment: Any random variable has an expected value and a variance. There is no quantity called an "expected variance" in glm theory or in probability theory in general. So I am not quite sure what you are after. It also isn't clear what $\tau$ represents in your notation. Is $\tau$ perhaps the inverse of $g$?

Comment: Assuming you are following Bent Jorgensen's notation, then $\tau(\theta)=\mu$ where $\theta$ is the canonical parameter. You can always differentiate $\tau$ to get the variance function but, no you cannot generally get the variance from the link function. That can be done only for canonical link functions, for which $g=\tau^{-1}$.

Comment: @GordonSmyth: Though brief, that's a complete answer if you want to make it one.